Subset of index that minimizes a sum of real values
Given a series of real numbers $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ with $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, is there an algorithm or method to find the subset of indices such that the absolute value of the sum of the values within the set achieves the minimum among all the sums over the subsets of the parts?
That is,
$$\min_{A \in \mathcal{P}(\{1, \ldots, n\})} \left| \sum_{p \in A} c_p \right|$$
At the moment, I don't have many ideas on how to approach the problem. I am unsure if the continuous version might be easier to solve by transitioning to characteristic functions or something similar.
Thanks for any help.

This seems similar to the knapsack problem (the decision form of which is NP-complete): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

This is the optimization version of the subset sum problem.
